# Принцип переноса текста в svg?

Tags: html, svg

В svg нет тэга `br` и для переноса используются атрибуты тэга `x` и `dy`

```
<text>
    <tspan x="0" textAnchor="middle" dy="1.2em">very long text</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" textAnchor="middle" dy="1.2em">I would like to linebreak</tspan>
  </text>
```

А какой принцип действия у этих атрибутов?
 Есть ли другие варианты переноса текста,  какой нибудь аналог **br**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Аналогом `<br>` в SVG является тег -  `<tspan>`, который размещается внутри `<text>`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"  
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     
   <text x="10" y="50">
            <tspan x="10" dy="1em">
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
            </tspan>
            <tspan x="10" dy="1em">
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
            </tspan>
            <tspan x="10" dy="1em">
                  Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
                  Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
            </tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

**"x", "y"** - абсолютные координаты начала текста, рассчитывается от начала координат исходного `svg`

**"dx", "dy"** - относительные координаты, задают сдвиг, перенос части текста.

- К `<tspan>` можно применять стили:

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%"  
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     
   <text x="10" y="50" >
            <tspan x="10" dy="1em" fill="red">
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
            </tspan>
            <tspan x="10" dy="1em" fill="blue">
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
                   Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
            </tspan>
            <tspan x="10" dy="1em" fill="green">
                  Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.  
                  Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю.
            </tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

- Используя  координаты `x` и `y` для абсолютного позиционирования букв в слове,  можно получить интересные результаты.

  `<tspan font-weight="bold" fill="red" 
  x="60 70 80 90" 
  y="85 75 65 55">
                  Выше,
          </tspan>`

Здесь координаты указаны парами для каждой буквы

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="280" height="100" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     
   <text fill="blue" font-family="Arial" 
         font-size="16"  >
        <tspan  x="30 40 50 60 70 80 90" 
               y="85 75 65 55 45 35 25 "> Быстрее, </tspan>                
        <tspan font-weight="bold" fill="red" 
               x="60 70 80 90"  y="85 75 65 55">
                Выше,
        </tspan>
        <tspan x="90 100 110 120 130 140 150" 
               y="85 75 65 55 45 35 25 ">
                Cильнее
        </tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

- Ещё один способ использования `<tspan>` - размещение внутри него
  символов Юникода.  Атрибуты "dx" и "dy"  используются для взаимного,
  относительного позиционирования элементов.

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathChain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>

<text font-size="36"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="grey" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathChain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#7441; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan>
<animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" attributeName="startOffset" values="1%;55%;1%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```

Связанная тема: [page-break-inside для SVG g тэгов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/891292/28748)